# How to change progress bar to use an image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar, element

Pretty much what the title says. Not much else I can add!

I'm using Windows Form Application.

Comment: You could say whether you're talking about WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, or something else entirely, because this isn't really a C# question, it's a question about whatever UI framework you're using.

Comment: Added what i am using. Windows form application. Sorry

Comment: I looked up several ways to change the progress bar color and make it smooth but none seemed to work with images. I have an image i want to use as the progress.

Comment: You want to stretch the image or gradually reveal it?

Comment: ok, updated to also allow reveal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pretty much write one simply by inherit Control, a couple of properties and then draw your image using the Paint event of the control.

I write this example as a basic control. It is attributed with defaults etc., but i wrote it in VB and translated to C# so no guarantee that everything work at first attempt.

You will still need to implement various error checks and so forth. The control stretches whatever image you define for it. If no image is defined it reverts to a default color.

**Update:** Added property to also allow revealing of image.

Use it for anything; modify as needed (original VB source below for this interested):

```
using System.ComponentModel;

[CLSCompliant(true)]
public class Progressbar : Control {

    [CLSCompliant(true)]
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue(100)]
    public int Maximum {
        get {
            return _maximum;
        }
        set {
            _maximum = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [CLSCompliant(true)]
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Value {
        get {
            return _value;
        }
        set {
            _value = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [CLSCompliant(true)]
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue(null.ToString())]
    public Image ProgressbarImage {
        get {
            return _progressbarImage;
        }
        set {
            _progressbarImage = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [CLSCompliant(true)]
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "DarkGray")]
    public Color ProgressbarColor {
        get {
            return _progressbarColor;
        }
        set {
            _progressbarColor = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [CLSCompliant(true)]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Behavior")]
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool RevealImage {
        get {
            return _revealImage;
        }
        set {
            _revealImage = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private bool _revealImage = true;
    private int _maximum = 100;
    private int _value = 0;
    private Image _progressbarImage = null;
    private Color _progressbarColor = Color.DarkGray;

    Progressbar() {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e) {

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Rectangle r = this.ClientRectangle;

        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, r, Color.Black, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);

        r.Inflate(-1, -1);
        r.Width = (int.Parse((r.Width 
                        * (_value / _maximum))) - 1);
        if ((r.Width < 1)) {
            return;
        }

        if (_progressbarImage == null) {
            Using (Solidbrush b = new SolidBrush(_progressbarColor)) {
                g.FillRectangle(b, r);
            }
        }
        else {
            g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            if (_revealImage) {
                g.DrawImage(_progressbarImage, r, r, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
            else {
                g.DrawImage(_progressbarImage, r);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Original VB source:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

<CLSCompliant(True)>
Public Class Progressbar

    <CLSCompliant(True),
    RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint),
    Browsable(True),
    Category("Appearance"),
    DefaultValue(100)>
    Public Property Maximum As Integer
        Get
            Return _maximum
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _maximum = value
            Me.Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property
    <CLSCompliant(True),
    RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint),
    Browsable(True),
    Category("Appearance"),
    DefaultValue(0)>
    Public Property Value As Integer
        Get
            Return _value
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _value = value
            Me.Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property
    <CLSCompliant(True),
    RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint),
    Browsable(True),
    Category("Appearance"),
    DefaultValue(CStr(Nothing))>
    Public Property ProgressbarImage As Image
        Get
            Return _progressbarImage
        End Get
        Set(value As Image)
            _progressbarImage = value
            Me.Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property
    <CLSCompliant(True),
    RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint),
    Browsable(True),
    Category("Appearance"),
    DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "DarkGray")>
    Public Property ProgressbarColor As Color
        Get
            Return _progressbarColor
        End Get
        Set(value As Color)
            _progressbarColor = value
            Me.Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property
    <CLSCompliant(True),
    Browsable(True),
    Category("Behavior"),
    DefaultValue(True)>
    Public Property RevealImage As Boolean
        Get
            Return _revealImage
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _revealImage = value
            Me.Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property


    Private _maximum As Integer = 100
    Private _value As Integer = 0
    Private _progressbarImage As Image = Nothing
    Private _progressbarColor As Color = Color.DarkGray
    Private _revealImage As Boolean = True

    Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)

    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)

        Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
        Dim r As Rectangle = Me.ClientRectangle

        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, r, Color.Black, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)

        r.Inflate(-1, -1)
        r.Width = CInt(r.Width * _value / _maximum) - 1
        If r.Width < 1 Then Return

        If _progressbarImage Is Nothing Then
            Using b As New SolidBrush(_progressbarColor)
                g.FillRectangle(b, r)
            End Using
        Else
            g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
            If _revealImage Then
                g.DrawImage(_progressbarImage, r, r, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
            Else
                g.DrawImage(_progressbarImage, r)
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Works like a charm!! Only thing is that there is an annoying border that i cannot get rid of!  Example http://screencast.com/t/bpS0O35rQJ

Comment: I got rid of it! thanks a ton!